# INVALID_RESOURCE_ID con api de paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Buenas chicos tengo el siguiente problema al implementar paypal al carrito de compras que estoy haciendo todo va normal hasta el momento de querer acceder a los detalles del pago

Me sale el siguiente error:

> {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"9a8e9b4297c84"}

Este es mi codigo:

```
  $venta = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/".$_GET['paymentID']);

  curl_setopt($venta, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($venta,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
  curl_setopt($venta, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ".$accesToken));

  $respuestaVenta = curl_exec($venta);

  print_r($respuestaVenta);
```

Ya probé con distintos datos que arroja la api de paypal pero con ninguno me da acceso

Comment: ¿Por qué usas cURL en lugar del [SDK  de PHP](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) que Paypal proporciona?

Comment: Utilizo curl porque así es como lo he visto así en https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: También hay documentación para usar los [SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/) en varios lenguajes, como Node, Python, **PHP**, entre otros. Definitivamente es mucho más sencillo con esas librerías que ya manejan todas las opciones para cada petición.